# Youcompleteme can't find std lib in class's method

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

I use Youcompleteme to auto complete my c++ code.

But I found can't find the std lib in class's method, like follows.

[image]

But in globe function, it works fine.

[image]

Also, ycm can't find the local lib, after I put the header in `/usr/local/include`

[image]

`ls /usr/local/include/ | grep brpc` get the `brpc` there.

I use the https://github.com/JDevlieghere/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py config.

But change the flags follows.

```
C_BASE_FLAGS = [
    ┊   '-Wall',
    ┊   '-Wextra',
    ┊   '-Werror',
    ┊   '-Wno-long-long',
    ┊   '-Wno-variadic-macros',
    ┊   '-fexceptions',
    ┊   '-ferror-limit=10000',
    ┊   '-DNDEBUG',
    ┊   '-std=c11',
    ┊   '-I/usr/lib/',
    ┊   '-I/usr/include/'
    ┊   ]

CPP_BASE_FLAGS = [
    ┊   '-Wall',
    ┊   '-Wextra',
    ┊   '-Wno-long-long',
    ┊   '-Wno-variadic-macros',
    ┊   '-fexceptions',
    ┊   '-ferror-limit=10000',
    ┊   '-DNDEBUG',
    ┊   '-std=c++11',
    ┊   '-xc++',
    ┊   '-I/usr/lib/',
    ┊   '-I/usr/include/'
    ┊   '-I/usr/local/lib'
    ┊   '-I/usr/local/include'
    ┊   ]
```

gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)

Comment: Are you able to build this file with the given settings? Also `-Wno-variadic-macros` and `-Wno-long-long` make no sense for C++

Comment: @VTT What do you mean by build this file?

Comment: build the file for which you want autocompletion to work, `raft.cpp` in this case (probably). That autocompletion engine works by compiling file using clang, dumping AST and looking up symbol names there.

Comment: @VTT It works. I think it is strange. It means if I want to use ycm to help me complete the code, I need to compile the file first.